# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') at Guild.fetchVanityData Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get the vanities of the servers the bot is in, and it is responding with this error.

```
var vanity = await guild.fetchVanityData()
console.log(vanity)
```

also tried docs method (same error):

```
var vanity = guild.fetchVanityData().then(res => console.log(`Vanity URL: https://discord.gg/${res.code} with ${res.uses} uses`));
```

If there's another method of getting the vanity URL and I'm missing it or I'm using this wrong, then please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: Your error states you are doing `<undefinedValue>.includes()` yet the code you show does not have any usage of `includes()`. Double check the file and line number shown in the error.

Comment: Well I've now realized that it's because the guild is unavailable, and the .includes() isn't in my code, it's in discord.js